# KafkaListener stops consuming with a new ListenerContainerFactory

Tags: spring-kafka

I want to add container customizer to config retries of KafkaListeners and as well adding RecoveryCallback for when retries are exhausted. In our Kafka library which is added as dependency, there is already a listener container factory:

```java
 @Bean
    public CustomConcurrentContainerListenerFactory kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
        CustomConcurrentContainerListenerFactory factory = new CustomConcurrentContainerListenerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(this.kafkaAvroMessageConverter);
        factory.setReplyTemplate(this.kafkaTemplate);
        return factory;
    }
```

`CustomConcurrentContainerListenerFactory` is custom container which extends `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`

In the application I added a new container factory which uses `ConsumerFactory` defined in the library and a ContainerCustomizer as shown below:

```java
@Bean("sendEmailListenerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory sendEmailListenerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);        
        return factory;
    }

@Component
public class ContainerCustomizer {

    public ContainerCustomizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory sendEmailListenerFactory) {
        sendEmailListenerFactory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getListenerId().equals("handleMediumPriorityEmails")) {
                container.getContainerProperties().setCommitRetries(2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

There are already existing KafkaListeners in the application and when I add `sendEmailListenerFactory` as the containerFactory to one of them, that listener stops consuming.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "handleMediumPriorityEmails",
            topics = ActorNotificationSendEmailCommand.TOPIC,
            containerFactory = "sendEmailListenerFactory")
    public void handleMedium(SendEmailCommand command) {
        consume(NotificationPriority.MEDIUM, command);
    }
```

I checked `bootstrap.server` on the container and they are fine. Where else I need to dig to find the issue.

Comment: Nobody can help with so little information; provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits the behavior so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: @GaryRussell I edited my post with more information. Please let me know what else I can add to elaborate more.

Comment: I need a complete, minimal, project; I can't imagine why changing the container factory, especially to a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`, would prevent a listener from working, when it was previously running with a custom factory; debug logging might help you; if not, I need a complete project so I can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell! Realized custom container factory resolves topics by prefixing a `kafka.namespace` So producer was publishing to `test.topicX` and consumer listening on `topicX` as it is using different container factory.